# How can I send an array with href attribute in php?

Tags: php, arrays

**load_displayreport.php**

This file contains an array

```
$fieldsString1="";

while ($reportRow1 = mysqli_fetch_array($reportResult1)) {    
    array_push($fieldNames, $reportRow1['field_name']);
    $fieldsString1.="reg.".$reportRow1['field_name'].",";
 }
```

I am sending this array with some parameters to another file called printdynamicreport.php

```
echo "<div class='print'>
<a href ='../print/printdynamicreport.php?hid=$hid&fieldsString1=$fieldsString1&tablename=$tablename&start=$start&stop=$per_page'> Save as pdf </a></div>";
```

**printdynamicreport.php**

Accepting the value of 'fieldsString1' in one variable.

`$fieldsString1 = $_GET['fieldsString1'];`

since I have to use this variable in javascript m doing following :

`var fieldsString1 = <?php echo $fieldsString1; ?>;`

Now my question, is this possible ? can I send an array and use it like the way I have used ? Is there any alternative ?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Passing complex data in GET request

**To build a link:**

```
$array = Array([contents of big array]);
$url = "page.php?" . http_build_query(Array(
   "array" => $array
));
```

**To read data from $_GET in page.php:**

```
$array = $_GET['array'];
```

That's it ;)

Docs:

- http://www.php.net/http_build_query

---

In your example:

**load_displayreport.php**

```
$query = http_build_query(Array(
    'fieldNames' => $fieldNames,
    'hid' => $hid,
    'tablename' => $tablename,
    'start' => $start
    'stop' => $per_page
));
echo "<div class='print'>
<a href ='../print/printdynamicreport.php?{$query}'> Save as pdf </a></div>"
```

**printdynamicreport.php**

```
$fieldNames1 = $_GET['fieldNames1'];
```

and

```
var fieldNames = <?php json_encode($fieldNames1); ?>
```

Comment: hey.. I have fetched the value of `$fieldNames1` in php but cant get the same value in javascript using
`var fieldNames = <?php json_encode($fieldNames1); ?>`

Comment: @newbie_n you may need to change it a little bit. See `var_dump($fieldNames1);` and convert it to desireable variable

Answer (score 1):

yes you can
here is a example to it

If you want to do this with an associative array, try this

```
$url = 'http://example.com/index.php?';
$url .= implode('&amp;', array_map(function($key, $val) {
    return 'aValues[' . urlencode($key) . ']=' . urlencode($val);
  },
  array_keys($aValues), $aValues)
);
```

callback

```
function urlify($key, $val) {
  return 'aValues[' . urlencode($key) . ']=' . urlencode($val);
}

$url = 'http://example.com/index.php?';
$url .= implode('&amp;', array_map('urlify', array_keys($aValues), $aValues));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create some string from this

`array(implode('|', $fieldsString1)),`

send this string , and on other side create array from

`string (explode('|', $fieldsString1))`

this will work like callback

Comment: thanks abhishek.. used urlencode and decode, that helped me.
Thanks to all for replying so quick. Will try all your suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`http_build_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) function.